# IPython Notebook Kernel getting dead while running Kmeans

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython, scikit-learn

I am running K-means clustering on some 400K observations with 12 variables. Initially as soon as I run the cell with Kmeans code, it would pop up a message after 2 mins saying the kernel is interrupted and would restart. And then it takes ages like as if the kernel got dead and the code won't run anymore.

So I tried with 125k observations and same no. of variables. But still the same message I got.

What is meant by that?. Does it mean ipython notebook is not able to run kmeans on 125k observations and kills the kernel?.

How to solve this?. This is pretty important for me to do by today. :(

Please advise.

Code I used:

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

```
    # Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
    # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=2,init='k-means++',n_init=10, max_iter=100)
kmeans.fit(Data_sampled.ix[:,1:])
cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
    # The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
    # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
    # clusters
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(Data_sampled.ix[:,1:],cluster_labels)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with SKLearn.  I don't know what's going on, but perhaps I can help debug a little.

Have you tried a degenerate case, such as 5 observations?  If this also fails, that indicates that the problem is *not* with the quantity of observations, and you can look elsewhere.  For instance, reduce iterations from 100 to 5; change n_init to make the algorithm do less work.

I'm guessing that it's more important to get a reasonable answer *today* than to get the best possible answer.

Comment: I Just tried for 62K obs only with 12 variables. Again I got the same message "The kernel appears to have died. Please restart again". After restarting it never completes. What is happening?. Can ipython not handle 100K obs also?.. 

I am running on Mac latest OS with 16GB memory.

Comment: From the docs, is this relevant? "In practice, the k-means algorithm is very fast (one of the fastest clustering algorithms available), but it falls in local minima. That’s why it can be useful to restart it several times."

Comment: Can you run what you want from common python interpreter?
Seems that it's problem in [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#bad-interaction-of-multiprocessing-and-third-party-libraries)
Do you using MAC OS? Python version is bigger than 3.4?

Also [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5115) may be related

Comment: Hmm, if n_jobs=1 then it may not use joblib, so problem definitely not in it.

Comment: I am using Mac OS and Anaconda Ipython dist. I am not sure why it should take so much time for just 42K obs. even for 42K and for random seed initialization it took 20 mins. For kmeans++ initialization it took 45 mins and not done. And I just have 12 features so it's not a broad dataset too.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, on Anaconda as well.  I've narrowed it down to the line that calculates the silhouette score causing the segfault, but I have no idea why that would be.

Answer (score 6):

From some investigation, this likely has nothing to do with iPython Notebook / Jupyter. It seems this is an issue with `sklearn`, which traces back to an issue with `numpy`. See related github issues `sklearn` [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4701) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4197), and the underlying numpy issue [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5533).

Ultimately, calculating the Silhouette Score requires calculating a very large distance matrix, and it seems that distance matrix is taking up too much memory on your system for large numbers of rows. For instance, look at memory pressure on my system (OSX, 8GB ram) during two runs of a similar calculation - the first spike is a Silhouette Score calculation with 10k records, the second ... plateau .. is with 40k records:

[image: memory pressure]

Per the related SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321683/python-scikit-learn-kmeans-is-being-killed-9-while-computing-silhouette-score/30321832), your kernel process is probably getting killed by the OS because it is taking too much memory.

Ultimately, this is going to require some fixes in the underlying codebase for `sklearn` and/or `numpy`. Some options that you can try in the interim:

- close every extraneous program running on your computer (spotify, slack, etc.), hope that frees up enough memory, and monitor memory closely while your script is running
- run the calculation on a temporary remote server with more RAM than your machine has and see if that helps (although since I think the memory use is at least polynomial with respect to the number of samples, this may not work)
- train your classifier with your full data set, but then calculate silhouette scores with a random subset of your data. (most people seem to be able to get this working with 20-30k observations)

Or, if you're smarter than me and have some free time, consider trying out contributing a fix to `sklearn` and/or `numpy` :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old, for people who might benefit...

Maybe discussion in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9943) can help. Setting n_jobs=1 solved it for me. However, note that there is a FutureWarning about n_jobs deprecation.