# kernel dies when performing optimization with scikit

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm performing some optimization with scikit on machine learning problem working with 75 mb file that has 42k rows and 784 columns containg numbers.
Working on jupyter notebook.

But kernel dies when I run the code. The same working with terminal.

Is there any way to handle this problem?

def train(self, X, Y):

```
   def train(self, X, Y):

    self.X = X
    self.Y = Y

    self.J = []

    params0 = self.N.getParams()

    options = {'maxiter':1, 'disp': True}

    _res = optimize.minimize(self.costFunctionWrapper, params0, jac=True,
                             method='BFGS', args = (X, Y),
                             options=options, callback = self.callbackF)
    self.N.setParams(_res.x)
    self.optimizationResults = _res
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, my research tell me that it's a memory outage.

A lot of people on [stackoverflow and github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573948/ipython-notebook-kernel-getting-dead-while-running-kmeans) of recommend using a `.py` script instead of a jupyter notebook but sometimes that does not help at all. Try to be careful on the memory you are using relative to your system's capabilities.